# Setting up separate raid5 on Debian

Tags: debian, raid, samba, raid5

I want to set up a NAS/share with SAMBA on Debian(squeeze) with Webmin, and i want a setup like this:

- 2x40GB(IDE), in RAID1 for distro/debian.
- 4x40gb(SATA), in RAID5 for storage/NAS

This is just experimental setup until i get a few SATA TB HDDs, but how am i suppose to set up the RAID, and should i use LVM?

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here on how to create a raid1 array using mdadm which you can boot from (well you won't strictly speaking boot from the raid itself): [Creating a partitioned raid1 array for booting a debian squeeze system](https://serverfault.com/questions/347241/creating-a-partitioned-raid1-array-for-booting-a-debian-squeeze-system/347451#347451)

Given you have sdc to f with 1 partition covering the whole disk creating a raid5 is even simpler, example:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sd[cdef]1
```

Or with a spare, you need 5 disks in this example, but you can create a raid5 with just 3 disks:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sd[cdefg]1
```

Syntax may not be exactly correct since I didn't try it out.